# How can I make sure the rotation has finished or the transform is facing the target?

Tags: unity, c#

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        LiftProcess();
        MoveProcess();
        TiltProcess();

        if (hasRotate == true)
        {
            Vector3 targetDirection = helicopterPlatform.transform.position - transform.position;
            Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, lookAtSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
        }
    }
```

I want ot make a check IF transform.rotation has finished and the transform is facing the newDirection then change the flag hasRotate to false. What check and how should I apply ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `if ( Vector3.Angle(newDirection, targetDirection) < thresholdDegrees)`, where you can set the threshold in degrees as tight as you like.

Comment: I'm getting errors since newDirection and targetDirection are Vector3 and not Quaternion and if I tried to put there the rotations it's never get to set the flag to false : if (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, helicopterPlatform.transform.rotation) <= thresholdDegrees)
        {
            hasRotate = false;
        }

Comment: Ah, whoops, I misread. Just use the vector version instead of the quaternion version. Edited to show this.